# PHP Fatal error on running bin/magento inventory:reservation:list-inconsistencies command

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, inventory, cli

I am getting this error when running `bin/magento inventory:reservation:list-inconsistencies`:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Inventory\Model\ResourceModel\IsProductAssignedToStock::execute() must be of the type string, integer given, called in /mydomain/http/vendor/magento/module-inventory-reservation-cli/Model/SalableQuantityInconsistency/FilterManagedStockProducts.php on line 56 and defined in /mydomain/http/vendor/magento/module-inventory/Model/ResourceModel/IsProductAssignedToStock.php:34
Stack trace:
#0 /mydomain/http/vendor/magento/module-inventory-reservation-cli/Model/SalableQuantityInconsistency/FilterManagedStockProducts.php(56): Magento\Inventory\Model\ResourceModel\IsProductAssignedToStock->execute(1091634, 1)
#1 /mydomain/http/vendor/magento/module-inventory-reservation-cli/Model/GetSalableQuantityInconsistencies.php(105): Magento\InventoryReservationCli\Model\SalableQua in /mydomain/http/vendor/magento/module-inventory/Model/ResourceModel/IsProductAssignedToStock.php on line 34
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Hey Greg, Were you able to solve this ? Appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: Due to my external stock management system, I completely disabled the "Reservation" system. Thank for your interest!

Comment: Could you please share how you disabled it ?

Comment: I used this module: https://github.com/AmpersandHQ/magento2-disable-stock-reservation so all credit to this guy ;)

Comment: To install it: composer require ampersand/magento2-disable-stock-reservation

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

**Here is the temporary fix.** If you really wanna get rid of this error then update below function by type casting to string.

> /vendor/magento/module-inventory-reservation-cli/Model/SalableQuantityInconsistency/FilterManagedStockProducts.php

Line 56 and 60

```
    /**
     * Remove all reservations with incomplete state
     *
     * @param SalableQuantityInconsistency[] $inconsistencies
     * @return SalableQuantityInconsistency[]
     * @throws LocalizedException
     * @throws SkuIsNotAssignedToStockException
     */
public function execute(array $inconsistencies): array
    {
        foreach ($inconsistencies as $inconsistency) {
            $filteredItems = [];
            foreach ($inconsistency->getItems() as $sku => $qty) {
                if (false === $this->isProductAssignedToStock->execute((string)$sku, $inconsistency->getStockId())) {
                    continue;
                }

                $stockConfiguration = $this->getStockItemConfiguration->execute((string)$sku, $inconsistency->getStockId());
                if ($stockConfiguration->isManageStock()) {
                    $filteredItems[$sku] = $qty;
                }
            }
            $inconsistency->setItems($filteredItems);
        }

        return $inconsistencies;
    }
```

Now run the command.

```
bin/magento inventory:reservation:list-inconsistencies
```

Courtesy : https://github.com/magento/inventory/issues/2522